# Local Audio file not playing - Icenium / Cordova

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova, icenium

I am having problem playing sound in Icenium Cordova 3.2 project on my iPhone 5S. I am using the following code:

```
 if (device.platform == "Android") {
        src = new Media("/android_asset/www/audio/multimedia.mp3");
    } else {
          src = new Media("audio/multimedia.mp3"); // this line runs on my device
    } 

  src.play();
```

The audio file multimedia.mp3 exists in a folder called `audio` under the main project folder. I've tried different paths like `/audio/multimedia.mp3` and `multimedia.mp3` and the sound is not playing on my device.

When I use an absolute path to an external URL (`http://somesite.com/audiofile.mp3`) the audio file plays on my device. I haven't tested the code in Android yet. Thanks.

Comment: Check the FileReader portion of this doc http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: Worked! - File plugin was disabled. Write and I will accept. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have miss to add `phonegap.js` plugin.So your FileReader is not working or may be forget to add file plugin.

Comment: file plugin was disabled. Thanks!